# Why is MongoDB user with the only privilege as "find" able to insert and update collection?

Tags: mongodb, permissions, authentication, role, mongodb-4.0

I want my user to have only `find` action privilege on a specific collection. However, when I create the user with the privilege, restart the `mongod` server and run the mongo shell again with `-u` `-p` and `--authenticationDatabase` parameters and run `insert` command on the collection, it successfully inserts the document in collection. Similarly, `update` command also works seamlessly for this user and the corresponding collection.

Here's the code for creating the user-

```
use testauth
db.createUser({user: "user", pwd: "password", roles: [{role: "readWrite", db: "testauth", privileges: [{resource: {db: "testauth", collection: "readonlycol"}, actions: ["find"]}]}]})
```

Followed by this, I restart the `mongod` server with `--auth` and run the mongo shell with authentication parameters.
When I go ahead and try to insert a document in the collection,  it works -

```
> use testauth
> db.readonlycol.insert({"key": "value"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
```

`update` also seems to work. The only command which doesn't work is `remove`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

according to https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/

the "readwrite" is to blame ...

> readWrite
>
> Provides all the privileges of the read role plus ability to modify data on all non-system collections and the system.js collection.
>
> The role provides the following actions on those collections:

- collStats
- convertToCapped
- createCollection
- dbHash
- dbStats
- dropCollection
- createIndex
- dropIndex
- find
- **insert**
- killCursors
- listIndexes
- listCollections
- remove
- renameCollectionSameDB
- **update**

Although the list also contains the remove - right .

Comment: what I wanna achieve is to allow the user to only read and write to the database, with write permissions on a specific set of collections and read on another. How can I achieve this? what if I give read role to the user and give `insert`, `delete` and `update` as privileges to the specific collections?